# Regex for ignoring undesirable words: "work" but not "manual work"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am searching the word `\bwork\b`

However, I don't want matches for `\bmanual work\b`.

What would be a Regex expression to match `\bwork\b`, but always IGNORING `\bmanual work\b` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a match to catch only "work" by itself

```
/(\b(?<!(?:\S|\s){1})work\b)/mig
```

it uses a look behind

to so it means that nothing can be before work

an alternative method you can use just

```
/(^\bwork\b)/mig
```

it will match work if it is on the start of the sentence

m - multiple lines
i - case insesitive
g - global

Comment: Thanks! I clarified the question. Could you give a hand?

Comment: code edited 
try this (\b(?<!(?:\S|\s){1})work\b)
if it is what you want, tell me =)

Comment: Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find any word 'work', but not if it is 'manual work'. This expression worked:

[^manual]\s+\bwork\b